# Breaking down a 3D model into patches

Tags: graphics3d

I have a 3D model, say the Stanford bunny, which is available in *Mathematica* examples.

```
 Import[ "http://exampledata.wolfram.com/bunny.noff.gz" ]
```

Also information such as the 3D coordinate of vertices and the normal at each vertex is available.

Now I'd like to divide the whole thing into $n$, say 10, non overlapping patches. Something like the patches on a football. Patches must contain more or less same number of points, but this is a soft constraint.

I see there is a function `FindShortestPath` in *Mathematica*. Maybe that function can help me? Since I am a new user I am not sure how I should approach the problem.

Comment: `FindShortestPath` is used for Graphs and I don't see a direct application to 3D graphics.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of `FindClusters`, although at the moment I don't see an easy way to apply it.

Comment: A vertex connection analysis (resulting in a graph) should be really useful here.

Comment: @YvesKlett I agree that vertex analysis should help, specially in cases like here were Polygons, hence connected vertexes, are known.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit long for a comment:

The following approach seems to work, but is veeeery slow for the bunny. I am sure there are many ways to speed things up... (especially the `Position` bit). Before optimizing too much, I present the approach (maybe your data is not as complicated? Or speed is no issue?)

Let

```
bn= Import[ "http://exampledata.wolfram.com/bunny.noff.gz" ]
```

then we use `FindClusters` (see its documentation for e.g. other `DistanceFunction`s)

```
fc = FindClusters[bn[[1, 2, 1]], 5];
```

(fixing 5 clusters). Then (the slow part...)

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
    bn[[1, 2]] /. 
      GraphicsComplex[v_, r__] :>   
      GraphicsComplex[v, r, 
          VertexColors -> (
             Switch[Position[fc, #][[1, 1]], 1, Red, 2, Blue,
                 3, Green, 4, Yellow, 5, Pink, _, Black] & /@ v)]}]
```

where we essentially just check which cluster the vertex is in and choose (using `Switch`) a color accordingly.

The resulting bunny:

[image]

Comment: Not so bad considering the bunny consists of a meager 69451 polygons ;-) The one downside might be that due to the non-convex shape (and holes) you might get disconnected areas of one color.

Comment: True - based on the data, one most probably has to play with the `DistanceFunction` or `Method` (of `FindClusters`) a bit to get the desired effect... since the OP is not very clear about the structure/size of the dataset, I figured I offer a general approach, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Not to worry, I *like* your rainbow bunny :-)

Comment: it looks both like a football and scary :)

Comment: hey, no kickin´ dem cute bunnies round ´ere!

Comment: @YvesKlett Take a look at the last picture http://stackoverflow.com/a/4464141/353410

Comment: @belisarius ooooooooohhhhh!

Comment: Thanks @PinguinDirk for the beautiful answer. It should be sufficient for my current needs. However, as Yves Klett also mentioned, it is prone to some errors. Ideally I am looking for some sort of **Marching Cubes** algorithm that measures the distance between two vertices as travelled on the surface!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a mottled bunny, you can do the partitioning by just choosing the points in order as they appear in the drawing (let `Partition` do the partitioning).

```
bn = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/bunny.noff.gz"];
tris = bn[[1, 2, 1]];
poly = bn[[1, 2, 2, 1, 1]];
lenPoly = Length[poly];
n = 10;
part = Partition[poly, Floor[lenPoly/n]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
   Table[{Hue[i/n], GraphicsComplex[tris, Polygon[part[[i]]]]}, {i, 1, n}]}]
```

[image]